# Flot: how to style numbers within bar-charts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, flot

I'm using [FlotCharts](http://www.flotcharts.org/) and it's plugin **flot.barnumbers** ([Demo](http://joetsoi.github.io/flot-barnumbers/)) to display charts.

I need to display the numbers within the bar, it works. Unfortunately I've no idea how to style the numbers and cannot find anything in the Docs or via Google.

I'd like to use something like (apparently not possible):

```
bars: {
    numbers: {
        numberFormatter: function(v, bar) {
            return '<div class="pimp-my-number-class">'+ v +'</div>';               
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Flot barchart, current and goal]

Does anyone have an idea, how to fix this problem?

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the nicest things about `flot` is that it provides the basics and then gets out of your way.  [Here's a quick code example where I've implemented this myself (ie no plugins).](http://jsfiddle.net/x4bgU/1)  It's short and sweet and you have complete control over appearance.

```
$(function() {

    dsHook = function(plot, canvascontext, series){
        for (var i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++){ // loop the series
           var offset = plot.offset(); // offset of canvas to body
           var dP = series.data[i]; // our data point
           var pos = plot.p2c({x: dP[0], y: dP[1]}); // position of point           
           var barWidth = plot.p2c({x: dP[0]+series.bars.barWidth, y: dP[1]}).left - pos.left; // calc width of bar
           pos.left += offset.left; pos.top += offset.top; //adjust position for offset
           var aDiv = $('<div></div>').css({'width':barWidth, 'background-color':'green','color':'white','text-align':'center','position':'absolute','left': pos.left,'top':pos.top}).text(dP[1]).appendTo("body"); // add an absolute div with the number
        }
    }

    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    somePlot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{
            data: d2,
            bars: { show: true }
        }],
        { hooks: { drawSeries: [dsHook] } }
    );
});
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Unfortunately I need it for horizontal charts with negative values as well. I edited your fiddle and appreciate if you take a look and help me again: http://jsfiddle.net/x4bgU/5/

Comment: I had the same requirement and used the above code. But the numbers dont scroll along with the bar graph. The numbers are fixed on the page. :( How do i make it work

Comment: @Jinxed, can you provide a jsFiddle demonstrating your problem?  What exactly are you scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

`flot.barnumbers` doesn't support styling of the inserted numbers.
You have to add that yourself to the code. 
Have a look at [Drawing text using a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Drawing_text_using_a_canvas).

Answer (score 1):

I would try to achive your desired layout by using a combination of annotations like [here](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/annotating/index.html) and a second data series behind your actual series. The second series then should have equal x values as your original series. To the corresponding y values you add a constant (e.g. 2).

You can style the annotations and the second series as you like. The fiddly part would be to place the annotations at correct positions.